# Can't use .indexof on JSON string because it has no method 'indexof' javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I have some JSON parsed, but I would like to take a link I get from the JSON, find an identifier in the link that makes it different (e.g. www.foo.com/IDENTIFIER/home), and have that identifier as a string to plug into another function that uses the identifier.

Here's the code where I try to use indexOf to find the preidentifier path index so I can then get the index of the identifier after it (that code hasn't been written yet because I'm stuck here). This also uses JSONP.

```
$.jsonp({
    "url": "http://foo.com&callback=?",
    "data": {
    "alt": "json-in-script"
    },
    "success": function (data) {
        var link = data[0].link;
        var jsonText = JSON.stringify(link);

        // the below code returns string
        console.log('jsonText string?'+typeof jsonText); 

        // the below code returns that this method has no object indexOf
        var index = jsonText.indexof("pre-identifier-path/"); 

    },
    "error": function () {
    }
});
```

Thank you for your time, sorry if this a tad confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method should be named [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp), it's case sensitive. Ex.:

```
jsonText.indexOf("pre-identifier-path/");
```

Answer (score 2):

The function is `indexOf()` i.e. capital O - it is case sensitive.

Comment: Wow, I'm a bit embarrassed I didn't catch that, but thanks so much. That fixed it.

Comment: It happens to the best of us. :)